# How do I make my account able to download "Mature"-rated games?

Tags: xbox-network

I have three accounts on my XBox (now it's two). The problem is the main account that I use is not the one that was made first, so when I go to download "Mature" demos it says that "this account is not permitted to download content with this rating". I can download stuff that is rated "Teen".

I have already gone to the settings and changed it to "Adult" but it still gives me the error. I have even deleted the account that was made first and it still won't allow me to.

How do I make my account able to download "Mature"-rated games?

Comment: We're onto you Kindergartener!

Comment: @DoozerBlake You're not his real dad!

Comment: @GnomeSlice just you wait, I'll show you! I'm going to run away and join the circus and be famous and have a pet lion!

Answer (score 7):

If you are over 18 and want to promote your account to an adult account, read the support article on [how to promote an Xbox LIVE child account to an adult account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945418)

This only works if your age according to the date of birth entered when the account was first created is over 18 (or whatever the legal adult age is where you live). If you entered the wrong date of birth, you have to create a new account.

Answer (score 1):

My XBox Live Account thinks I'm still 16 and I can still download "M" rated content. This is the way I do it:

For DLC's like AC:Brotherhood:

> 1. Put game disc in console
> 2. Launch game
> 3. At the menu go to "extras"/"dlc"
> 4. When the DLC list is loaded press the button that opens the guide window to view DLC's while still in-game ("x" for ex.)
> 5. Select the content you wish to download.
> 6. On the following window, select "download" and press the "a" button.
> 7. After the download is complete, you will now have your content.

For game demos and other non-DLC items, you must use a Kinect.

> 1. Using ONLY voice commands; locate the content you wish to download.
> 2. Once there, open the download window to confirm your download (again, ONLY using voice commands!)
> 3. Finally, using your hand, select "download" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if Content Controls are turned on?

When at the Dashboard, go to the Settings tab, and select Family. You can either turn Content Controls off, or change the rating level for games that is acceptable to download by selecting Ratings and Content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but if you set your account age to say that you are under 18, you will be unable to download mature content.

If you really want to download it, make another account and set your age to 20. I don't normally condone lying, but come on Microsoft, >50% of your M rated game fanbase is <18. (Don't quote me on that).

Comment: I suppose they haven't taken into account that people age over time?

Comment: @kotekzot When XBL checks your age, it obviously gets your current age. M$ isn't that dumb.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, at least the problem will resolve itself with time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating another account with a birthdate indicating that you are 21 years old.

1. Sign in with the second account (the 21+ one) MAKE SURE IT HAS BEEN SIGNED UP FOR XBOX LIVE!! (Does not have to be a gold membership)
2. In the store, search for what game you want to download (or demo if you have no points)
3. After the game has FINISHED downloading completely, sign out and sign in with your primary account.
4. Enjoy the game! (Can be found in "games" section or in recent downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it just worked for me while trying to purchase a game with a T rating for my son and maybe someone can confirm if it works for them.

While he was logged in with his own XBL account he couldn't search for the game due to the rating. I signed out of XBL and then did the search again for the game and was able to find it. I then selected it and was prompted to sign in with an XBL account and I chose his. I was then prompted for payment options and after that process I was able to download the game to his XBL account.

Again, looking for confirmation from others as to how this works for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go onto Xbox.com then sign in with your main profile that is parent to the others. Then go to accounts. There you can click the profile that your wanting to modify, and from there you can edit all privacy and rating settings.

Comment: Xbox.com/accounts